# React - Passed down variable is empty

Tags: reactjs, ethers.js

The App consists of

- App.js
- Navbar component
- NFT component

Navbar has a searchbar, where you put in an address and get metadata (works, but the 2 console.logs are empty the first time)

When I want to access the metadata in NFT the image and the name are empty (sometimes the name gets displayed)

I think its fixable with useEffect hook, but I have no idea how I should change my code.

**I answered questions in the comments**

**App.js**

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [image, setImage] = useState("")


  const getNFT = async (address) => {
    
    const provider = new  ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

    const contractAddress= "0x49cF6f5d44E70224e2E23fDcdd2C053F30aDA28B"
    
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider)
    
    const count = parseInt(await contract.balanceOf(address))

    const tokenOfOwnerByIndex = parseInt(await contract.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address, 0));

    const tokenUri = await contract.tokenURI(tokenOfOwnerByIndex);

    //console.log(tokenUri)

    const tokenMetaData = await fetchMetaData(tokenUri);

    setName(tokenMetaData.name)
    setImage(tokenMetaData.image)

    console.log(name)
    console.log(image)
    
  }

  const fetchMetaData = async (tokenUri) => {
    const res = await fetch(tokenUri)
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar getNFT={getNFT}/>
      <NFT name={name} image={image}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Navbar.jsx**

```
const Navbar = ({getNFT}) => {

  const getNFTs = event =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('SearchBar')[0].value === "" || 0 ){
      alert("Enter an address")
    }else{
      const address = document.getElementsByClassName('SearchBar')[0].value
      getNFT(address)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Navbar">
        <div className="SearchField">
            <input type="text" className="SearchBar" placeholder="0x..000"></input>
            <button type="button" className='SearchButton' onClick={getNFTs}>Load</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**NFT.jsx**

```
const NFTCard = ({name}, {image}) => {
  return (
    <div className='NFTCard'>
        <p className="name">{name}</p>
        <img src={image} alt={name + ".png"} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: First, you have to decide when the 1st getNFT call is going to happen. If you have a default `address` then you can use a useEffect to call your NFT when the component first loads.

Comment: setState is async so it wont change data immediately. Console.log after setState can show data before it is changed.

Comment: Be aware that setState is an async function. So if you console.log you state right after you update it, it might not have been updated yet. Try moving your console.log ouside the getNFT function and check if it is still null for the first time. https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bose-dzspfl

Comment: `When I want to access the metadata in NFT the image and the name are empty (sometimes the name gets displayed)` - add loading indicator, because oyu dont know when fetching is completed. Thats why sometimes you can see name and image.

Comment: The 1st getNFT gets called when I enter an address so its empty in the beginning.

I ve added a button in NFT that console.logs the name and the image

name is always there after getNFT but the image is always undefined

Ty for the information about setState(async) 

Is this the right way without useEffect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve solved it.
The problem was passing down the variables.

If I do this

```
({name}, {image}) 

name = name
image = undefined
```

but if I do this

```
({name, image})

name = name
image = image
```

Ty for your help

Comment: Okay. I understand now. I see you have solved your problem. I'll delete my answer now.